# Google Analytics's upgrade to universal analytics stuck

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, universal-analytics

Currently upgrading from from old GA code to universal analytics. The new code snippet is on the website but Google is still saying it needs to be implemented.

This is the universal code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <!-- GA Universal Code 2014-08 -->
eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,d){e = function (c) {
    return(c < a ? '' : e(parseInt(c / a))) + ((c = c % a) > 35 ? String.fromCharCode(c + 29) : c.toString(36))
};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--){d[e(c)]=k[c]||e(c)}k=[function(e){return d[e]}];e=function(){return'\\w+'};c=1};while(c--){if(k[c]){p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c])}}return p}('C(c="K.J.v",k="h",8=c.3,z="",i=0;i
    <c.3;i++)-1==k.6(c.2(i))?(4=c.2(i),z+=4):(4=(k.6(c.2(i))-8+k.3)%k.3,z+=k.2(4));5.I==z&&(!9(t,e,c,n,a,i,r){t.o = a, t[a] = t[a] || 9(){(t[a].q=t[a].q||[]).s(g)},t[a].l=1*p m,i=e.j(c),r=e.f(c)[0],i.u=1,i.E=n,r.H.G(i,r)}(M,5,"L","//F.y-7.x/7.w","b"),b("A","B-D-1","d"));',49,49,'||charAt|length|ltr|document|indexOf|analytics|shift|function||ga||auto||getElementsByTagName|arguments|q1Rj80GyBp4LthrnQI7Zu5XECmblkUSwKTWPH6MNzO2exgadv3csJVFYiDAf9o||createElement|||Date||GoogleAnalyticsObject|new|||push||async|tE3|js|com|google||create|UA|for|849615|src|www|insertBefore|parentNode|domain|30p7tBsN0YhHEpBw|YYY|script|window'.split('|'),0,{}))
</script>
```

Here is the message that Google says:
[image]

Any help or advice would be super useful, Thanks.

Comment: Just of of curiosity, why do you use a "packed" version of the tracking code that is actually larger (and presumably less performant - eval, seriously ?) than the original code ? Plus, did you test if the message disappears if you use the code as suggested by Google ?

Comment: The packed version was used because of false data coming from a cloned version of the website. Would you suggest using the standard code and then blocking the domain from GA using a custom exclusion? I am just trying the standard code again to see if it works.

Comment: I concur with @EikePierstorff, there's, more than likely, issues because of your version of the code. Google's snippets are meant to be used as is, in an unmodified, unaltered, uncensored(?) fashion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to revert back to the old code and complete the upgrade that way.